# Convertir un string a class c#?

Tags: c#

es posible en C# acceder a los métodos de una clase que esta en string? 
Ejemplo :

```
string Clase = @"using System; 
    using System.Text; 
    namespace MiEspacio {  
        public class Class1 
        {
            public Class1() { } 
            public string Saludar() 
            { 
               return 'Hola Mundo'; 
            } 
        } 
    }"
```

O cómo crear una clase a partir de dicho string en tiempo de ejecución sin complilarla en disco?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Answer (score 2):

Sí, es posible usando [las clases de .NET para compilar código](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/304655/how-to-programmatically-compile-code-using-c-compiler). Ejemplo sencillo que genera un ejecutable:

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string source = @"
            using System;  
            using System.Text;  
            namespace MiEspacio
            {
                public class Program
                {
                    public static void Main()
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(""Hola Mundo"");
                    }
                }
            }
        ";

        var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters();
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
        parameters.OutputAssembly = "c:\\temp\\hola.exe";
        var results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);
        if(results.Errors.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ok!");
        }
        else
        {
            var errors = results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Select(e => e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", errors).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perdon la demora, entiendo el ejemplo, gracias. El tema es que esta generando un exe y en realidad lo que busco es ofuscar de forma eficiente cierta parte del codigo, pensé en ofuscar una clase entera por lo que quiero es pasarla a string que es muy facil para luego aplicarle aes y una vez tenga esos bytes ponerlos dentro de un dongle (hardware), y que el programa lea la memoria del dongle recuperando los bytes para luego obtener el string (clase en ese formato) y en MEMORIA RAM compilar la dll y acceder a sus metodos.